# g++ refuses to compile because of maximum instantiation depth

Tags: c++, templates, g++, cross-compiling

I want to make container-types printable, but if it's default-printable(like `std::string`), it should use it's own method.

So I wrote the following code.
(this is just part of my code, so I used SFINAE)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_printable : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_printable<T, std::void_t<
    decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>
  > : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_container<T, std::void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().end()),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().size())>
  > : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_container<T>::value && !is_printable<T>::value, int> = 0>
std::ostream&
operator << (std::ostream& os, const T& v) {
  // do something
  return os;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
  std::string s = "123";

  std::cout << v << std::endl;  // part 1
  std::cout << s << std::endl;  // part 2
}
```

So part `1` should call custom operator overloaded function, and part `2` should call default STL's function.
It works well in clang++ and Android NDK compiler, but not in g++.

g++ error:

```
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> struct is_printable<T, std::void_t<decltype ((std::cout << declval<T>()))> > [with T = std::vector<int>]’:
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:24:65:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> > std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>; typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:11:24:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> struct is_printable<T, std::void_t<decltype ((std::cout << declval<T>()))> > [with T = std::vector<int>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:24:65:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> > std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>; typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:11:24:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> struct is_printable<T, std::void_t<decltype ((std::cout << declval<T>()))> > [with T = std::vector<int>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:24:65:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> > std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>; typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:11:24:   [ skipping 889 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:24:65:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> > std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>; typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:11:24:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> struct is_printable<T, std::void_t<decltype ((std::cout << declval<T>()))> > [with T = std::vector<int>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:24:65:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> > std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>; typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:11:24:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> struct is_printable<T, std::void_t<decltype ((std::cout << declval<T>()))> > [with T = std::vector<int>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:24:65:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> > std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>; typename std::enable_if<(is_container<T>::value && (! is_printable<T>::value)), int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]’
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:34:16:   required from here
/tmp/tmp.wPDJE0CJxf/main.cpp:11:42: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
     decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
compilation terminated.
```

g++ version

```
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is there any wrong in my codes, or it's compiler's defect?

Comment: I'm guessing because you've added an operator for printing containers they become `printable` but printable needs to check the operator and the operator needs to check printable leading to infinite recursion

Comment: Your code has a logic error, when defining `operator <<` to check if your type is printable, you're asking the compiler for the return type of `operator <<` of that type... which you are defining right now.

Comment: @Kaldrr No it's intended. Since compiler cannot find matching function at that moment, substitution will fail for that function. So compiler will search for other functions.

Comment: Not sure program is not ill-formed NDR. `is_printable<std::vector<int>>` is at first `std::false_type` "then" `std::true_type`.